# Why can't I see my writing

Tags: html, css

Hi I've been testing a page out and its been going well until I tried to make my logo "GJB" color:white. When i do this can't see the writing anymore. I don't know why this is happening? Here is my code and if you go ***header{ color:black}*** and change it to white is disappears. http://jsfiddle.net/wy0doL5d/

```
<div class="pic"><img src="img/lgo.png"></div>
    <header>
        <div id="header-container">
       <nav> 
          http://jsfiddle.net/wy0doL5d/#update <h1>GJB</h1> 
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a>About</a></li>
            <li><a>Shop</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

    </header>

    <section class="home-intro">
    <div id="container">
    <h2>Hello there how you doing</h2>
    </div>
    </section>
    <main>
     <div id="container">
    <p>Hello there how you doing</p>
    </div>

    </main>
    <main>
     <div id="container">
    <p>Hello there how you doing</p>
    </div>

    </main>
    <main>
     <div id="container">
    <p>Hello there how you doing</p>
    </div>

    </main>
    <main>
     <div id="container">
    <p>Hello there how you doing</p>
    </div>

    </main>
```

Comment: First you need to clean up your code. Amongst others same id on several div's, non valid css properties, floats without width/height etc. ... it's a real mess and many issues will likely go away when this is fixed.

Comment: because it inherits from 'nav'. Your code is not valid (ids must be unique and "mix-blend-mode: darken;" not dark). Use better plnkr.co

Answer (score 1):

It is rather odd that you can see other colors - if you change to red, yellow, or pretty much anything besides white it's still visible. Honestly couldn't tell you why that happens - thought it might have something to do w/your use of blend modes in a few places (darken blending would remove white), but removing those didn't seem to help.

Your "header" also didn't have a height property. If you add one you see that the "GJB" text becomes visible regardless of color.

```
header{
  background-color: #1800ff;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 60px;
  color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wy0doL5d/6/

Comment: I think the blend modes are a big part of it. Here I put in a valid image and you can see the text http://jsfiddle.net/wy0doL5d/7/

Comment: @cocoa - Blend mode seems to have rather inconsistent browser support. Chrome works ok if I change modes around ("screen" shows white, while darken & multiply show dark as expected), but latest Firefox is screwy & hides the white GBJ text even while showing other white text. BTW you had `dark` instead of `darken` for blend mode of `pic`, but it's still screwy after fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because CSS is cascading. It will trickle down to descendants. You want to put color on a lower element in your CSS.